# Failed to use string in if statements

Tags: java, string, if-statement, user-input

Hello sorry for this bold question but im not sure how to solve my needs on line 24 and 30 in the code. Also im getting error messages on line 33 and 22 so it would be awesome if you could solve those.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckOrder {


    public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Scanner userInputStarters = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String menu;
    public static String check;
    public static String TheRestroom = "The Restroom";
    public static String Restroom = "Restroom";
    public static String Eat = "Eat";
    public static String ToEat = "To Eat";
    public static String restOrEat;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Hello and Welcome to the SOMETHING restaurant. Would you like to eat or use the restroom?");
        public static restOrEat = userInput.NextInt();

        if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom || Restroom)) {

            System.out.println("Please go ahead to the restroom, it's over there.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Eat || ToEat)) {

            System.out.print("What would you like to eat for starters? Press 1 for Cheese & Bacon, 2 for Sald (With options) and 3 for noodles");
            public static String starter = userInputStarters;

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: please post a MCCVE (like a [MCVE] but compilable). Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Comment: Did you try putting a `sys.out` and checking. Also `trim` might be needed for user input.

Comment: You should not check `equalsIgnoreCase` with one go.

Comment: What do you think `TheRestroom || Restroom` do?

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator can not be applied to java.util.String.

```
restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Eat || ToEat);
```

The both variables `Eat` and `ToEat` are Objects from the the class java.util.String. That's why the `||` operator does not work in this case.

Change it to:

```
restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Eat) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(ToEat);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in a main method you can't use `public static`. Also `restOrEat` sounds like is supposed to be a yes or no string, so you can't say `nextInt()`. use either `next()` if its just one word or `nextLine()` if you want a whole line. And in the if statements you can't use the `||` operator inside the `equalsIgnoreCase()` call but you need to make two and put the `||` in the middle.

Try this if it fits what you need.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckOrder {

    public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Scanner userInputStarters = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String menu;
    public static String check;
    public static String TheRestroom = "The Restroom";
    public static String Restroom = "Restroom";
    public static String Eat = "Eat";
    public static String ToEat = "To Eat";
    public static String restOrEat;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Hello and Welcome to the SOMETHING restaurant. Would you like to eat or use the restroom?");
        restOrEat = userInput.next();

        if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Restroom)) {

            System.out.println("Please go ahead to the restroom, it's over there.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Eat) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(ToEat)) {

            System.out.print("What would you like to eat for starters? Press 1 for Cheese & Bacon, 2 for Sald (With options) and 3 for noodles");
            int starter = userInputStarters.nextInt();

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: will you bother to explain what it is?

Comment: Still you didn't explain what cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write 'public static' the way you are writing inside the main method.

```
if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Restroom)) {
```

Replace both of your lines with above reference

Answer (score 0):

First of all the if statements are incorrect, they are supposed to be like this  `if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Restroom)) {`

Secondly, you can't have the public and static keywords infront of the variables inside methods.

So change the `public static restOrEat` (You're also missing the object definition) to `int restOrEat` (Seemingly you already defined it as a String in the class) and the `NextInt` is supposed to be `nextInt()`

Also check this out [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems:

- Or condition (`||`) should be between to checks

  ```
  if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom) || restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Restroom)) { }
  ```
- You defined `restOrEat` as class variable but redefined it (sort of) in `main`

  ```
  public static restOrEat = userInput.NextInt();
  ```
- `public static` is not valid syntax for a method variable (not even separately) and you don't have the type.
- `userInput.NextInt();` will return `int` but `restOrEat` is `String`. Use `userInput.next()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CheckOrder {


public static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Scanner userInputStarters = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String menu;
public static String check;
public static String TheRestroom = "The Restroom";
public static String Restroom = "Restroom";
public static String Eat = "Eat";
public static String ToEat = "To Eat";
public static String restOrEat;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Hello and Welcome to the SOMETHING restaurant. Would you like to eat or use the restroom?");
    restOrEat = userInput.next();

    if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(TheRestroom)||restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Restroom)) {

        System.out.println("Please go ahead to the restroom, it's over there.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    if (restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(Eat)||restOrEat.equalsIgnoreCase(ToEat)) {

        System.out.print("What would you like to eat for starters? Press 1 for Cheese & Bacon, 2 for Sald (With options) and 3 for noodles");
        int starter = userInputStarters.nextInt();

    }
}
}
```

Here is the solution for your problem.